# JavaScript scroll based animation is choppy on mobile

Tags: javascript, animation, mobile, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have 2 divs (left and right) and i want to scroll the left based on the right.
https://jsfiddle.net/3jdsazhg/2/

This works fine on desktop, but when i change to mobile, it's not smooth anymore...
This can be noticed very easily, by changing

```
_left.style.top = _content.scrollTop - (_content.scrollTop * ratioLeftRight) + 'px';
```

to

```
_left.style.top = _content.scrollTop + 'px';
```

Where it should act as a fixed positioned div

1. I would like to know the exact reason why this isn't smooth... I know that it's not the animation. Simple animation on the div is smooth, the issue comes up when it's based on scroll.
2. How can i make this animation smooth?

Comment: I guess it depends on how often the specific browser updates the `scrollTop` property of the element when being scrolled?

Comment: This happens in chrome as well, if you open inspect element and choose mobile view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to think out a solution.

From my point of view, i'm guessing the mobile view fires the scroll event less often and because we are scrolling the wrapper, we first scroll the whole page and then scroll back with js the left part and because it's different from the desktop version, this issue becomes visible...

The solution was to change the left side to fixed position, and substract from the top instead of adding to it.

```
_left.style.top = -(_content.scrollTop * ratioLeftRight) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably choppy because it's being fired ALOT when being scrolled, in fact i'm pretty sure IOS mobile pauses the javascript execution whilst the user is scrolling.

Instead I'd suggest using an interval, you could tweak the time between each interval to what feels good for your use-case.

Although it may seem intensive that it's firing this logic every X millisecond when using the scroll event you could be firing the event off hundreds of times per second, which is going to be far more intensive and noticeable to a user using a device with limit processing power.

```
(function () {
     var interval = null,

         //Currently set at 0.4 seconds, play with the code
         //and change this value to see what works best for 
         //this use-case
         time_between_interval = 400;

     setInterval(scrollLogic, time_between_interval); 

     function scrollLogic () {
         //The function body of what you're assigning 
         //to the scroll event.
     } 

     //I have omitted clearing the interval but you would want to do that, perhaps on page change, or something.

     //clearInterval(interval);
})();
```

Comment: that's not the issue, in that case it would happen the same thing on desktop version as well and just in case i already tried this...

Comment: @Inc33 The processor on a desktop is undoubtedly going to dwarf the processor on a mobile device so you would not notice it on desktop as it is able to handle the vast amount of successive function calls. Think of games, a game that isn't smooth on your mobile is likely to be very smooth on your desktop. Hooking into the scroll event is a bad practice for mobile full stop :).

Comment: you can reproduce this issue, by opening it on desktop, then emulate mobile version. That way you would have the processor of the same PC and still have the same issue...

Comment: Have you tried this code on an actual mobile device? Also did you play with the time_between_interval value much?